# Как получить название загружаемого файла?

Tags: java, android, файлы, download

Есть WebView (web) настраиваю скачивание файлов, и столкнулся с проблемой, нужно в методе onDownloadListener() через который я роботаю, получить имя загружаемого файла...

```
 web.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
 public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype,          long contentLength) {
 request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
 request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
 request.setNotificationVisibility(request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
 /* ################# FILE NAME #################*/
 request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "");
 /* ################# FILE NAME #################*/
 DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
 dm.enqueue(request);}});
```

Строка в которой нужно указать название файла отмечена комментарием:

```
      /* ################# FILE NAME #################*/
```

Там в скобки нужно указать имя загружаемого файла..
Если туда ввести какоето слово например: qwerty
то все скачиваемые файлы будут подписанны этим словом, даже формата типа (.jpg .zip .mp3) не дописивает...
Кто знает как узнать имя загружаемого файла?
Помогите, желательно примером кода...

Comment: Может в качестве имени файла взять часть строки `url` после последнего слеша?

Comment: @diraria можете код написать, как Вы себе это представляете?

Comment: diraria как????

Comment: Примерно так: `url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать что-то наподобие этого:

```
public static String getFileName(String url) {
    if (url.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Url can not be empty");
    }
    String fileName = null;
    String arrayString[] = url.split("/");
    if (arrayString.length > 1) {
        fileName = arrayString[arrayString.length - 1];
        return fileName;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Url is not valid, url: " + url); //or change on something more smart
    }
}
```

Либо вот так, как подсказал @diraria

```
public static String getFileName(String url) {
        if (url.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Url can not be empty");
        }
        String fileName = null;
        int i = url.lastIndexOf('/');
        if (i>-1) {
            fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            return fileName;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Url is not valid, url: " + url); //or change on more smart
        }
    }
```

Comment: А чем не понравился `url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)`?) Он, кстати, шикарно работает для строки без слеша.

Comment: Работает шикарно, не спорю, и в разы быстрее моего варианта, но если не обложить проверками, можем получить некорректное имя файла. В общем сейчас переписал под твой вариант, симбиоз работает даже лучше твоего и моего вариантов (в 90% запусков), так что щас выкачу upd

`FreemakeVideoDownloaderSetup.exe 
1718854 //мой первоначальный
FreemakeVideoDownloaderSetup.exe 
50815 //твой
FreemakeVideoDownloaderSetup.exe 
40806` //симбиоз